# Flutter - How to refresh ListView on data recive from another class

Tags: flutter, listview, refresh

I recive data from datareciver listener and added to my object list but I cant upload listview from another class. So is there a listener for listview to update when data recive.

I put all my class and code

ContentModel.dart   -which is my Model

```
class ContentModel{
  
  String dialogID;

  DialogModel(this.dialogID);

}
```

Global.dart  --Global class to store list

```
class Globals {
  
  static List<ContentModel> dialogList =new List<ContentModel>();
 
}
```

main.dart  --main view to display my list when its recive

```
   List<ContentModel> _contentModel = Globals.dialogList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child:ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                    itemCount:_contentModel.length,
                    reverse: false,
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) =>
                        buildChat(_contentModel[index]))
    ));
  }
```

DataReciver.dart  --Data reciver can recive any time and save it on global list

```
  class QuickBloxListenerManager{

       onMassageRecive(Function fun) async
      {
          try {
        await QB.chat.subscribeChatEvent(QBChatEvents.RECEIVED_NEW_MESSAGE,
            (data) {
              print( "New Message Arrive...");
          Map<String, Object> map = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(data);
          Map<String, Object> payload =
              new Map<String, dynamic>.from(map["payload"]);
 
  ContentModel newMsg = new ContentModel();
      
      newMsg.dialogID=payload['id'];

            Globals.messageList.messages.add(newMsg);

        }, onErrorMethod: (error) {
         
        });
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      
      }
    
      }
      
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can look into the [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html), which is a widget very common in Flutter apps to update the UI based on data change.
In this case, you can implement the flow of your app like this:

1. Create a StreamController

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class QuickBloxListenerManager{
    final _controller = StreamController<List<ContentModel>>();

    Stream<List<ContentModel>> contentModelStream => _controller.stream;

    // ... other lines
}
```

2. In your data receiver, after receive new data, add that data to the Stream

```dart
onMassageRecive() async {

      try {
          // ... other lines
      
          newMsg.dialogID=payload['id'];

          // Here I'm seeing you're quoting the dialogList, so I will use that list in the code
          Globals.dialogList.add(newMsg);

          _controller.add(Globals.dialogList);
       // ... other lines
      }
```

3. In your UI, use the StreamBuilder to listen to the data:

```dart
class SomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  // ... other lines

  // Initiate your QuickBloxListenerManager class
  final QuickBloxListenerManager _manager = QuickBloxListenerManager();

  // Get your data in the initState()
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _manager.onMassageRecive();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
        child: StreamBuilder<List<ContentModel>>(
          stream: _manager.contentModelStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
            List<ContentModel> _contentModel = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                    itemCount:_contentModel.length,
                    reverse: false,
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) =>
                        buildChat(_contentModel[index]))
                  )
             );     
          } 
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clean and helpfull answer.